# Remove / Override default styles from materialui components

Tags: reactjs, styles, overriding, material-ui

I'm trying to change the background color of the menuitem popover. But I am unable to remove paddingtop and paddingBottom from menuitem. It's kind of annoying because some materialui components inherit styles from paper, list, menu and etc. Is there a clean and efficient way to work around this? For eg, using overrides in theme and etc.

I have experiment and I know it can be done using inline styles/classes but i do not wish to use that method. I've tried using ListProps={{disablePadding: true}}, MenuProps={{{disablePadding: true}}. But it Doesn't work.

```
       <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <Select
            value={value.groupId}
            onChange={handleChange}
            MenuProps={{
                getContentAnchorEl: null,
                anchorOrigin: {
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "left",
                },
              }}
            classes={{
                icon:  isDarkMode ?  classes.iconLight :classes.icon,

            }}
            ListProps={{disablePadding: true}}
            inputProps={{
                name: 'groupId',
                id: 'group-machines',
              }}
            >

        {
            equipmentgroups.map(equipmentgroup =>
            <MenuItem 
            style={isDarkMode ? {backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark} : 
            {backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main}}
            className={classes.menuItemDisplay}  
            value={equipmentgroup.groupId}
            key={equipmentgroup.groupId}
            >{equipmentgroup.groupName}</MenuItem>
            )

        }

            </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

I'm still GETTING this when I'm inspecting the element.

```
        .MuiList-padding-370 {
             padding-top: 8px;
             padding-bottom: 8px;
         }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `MenuProps={{ MenuListProps: { disablePadding: true } }}`.

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    age: "",
    name: "hai"
  });

  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues(oldValues => ({
      ...oldValues,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={values.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          MenuProps={{ MenuListProps: { disablePadding: true } }}
          inputProps={{
            name: "age",
            id: "age-simple"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

[image: Edit Select without padding]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that you have to go through so many layers. The inspect element just stated MUIList. Any advice to do this quicker? I found another method too. By adding, 
                overrides: {
                     MuiList:{
                        padding: {
                           paddingTop: 0,
                           paddingBottom: 0
                     }
                  },
to my createMUItheme.
Is this method advisable?

Comment: Using the theme is fine, but the exact approach you are using will affect all List elements — not just Select/Menu. If that is what you want, then it is fine.